# html dynamically add event listeners without knowing id

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am creating lots of  select lists ( drop downs) when I build the page.  The drop downs are based on external data files, so I set the id's at runtime.  Something like

```
<% name="TypeA" + specialIDString %>
<select  id="<%= name %>" >
blah
blah 
</select>
```

How do I then add an event listener, since I don't know the ID ahead of time?  Can I search the DOM for all id's with "TypeA" in the id, and just add a listener to each one of them?

I know how to trigger an onLoad() method in javascript, after the page is loaded, I just want to know how to search the DOM to find ID's with a particular string in them.  Thanks.

Comment: You could also throw a class on there to additionally set those elements apart, which would be more straightforward than matching part of the id.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the record, the vanilla JavaScript answer:

```
function getElementsByIdStartsWith( type, idStartsWith ) {
    var arr = [],
        all = document.getElementsByTagName( type );

    for ( var i = 0; i < all.length; i++ ) {
        if ( all[i].id.indexOf( idStartsWith ) === 0 ) {
            arr.push( all[i] );
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

and then:

```
var selects = getElementsByIdStartsWith('select', 'TypeA');
```

Now you can use for loop to bind handlers to each element from the array.

Comment: +1 Why would the vanilla JavaScript answer be *just for the record*?

Comment: +1 - Just an idea, you could check for `querySelectorAll` and if it is supported use that instead, otherwise fallback to your solution.

Comment: +1 Because it's faster, simpler and more portable. Why would you want that otherwise? You could also include a qSA fork if available: `  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('select[id^=TypeA]');`

Comment: I was curious about the performance difference between `getElementsByTagName` + a filter vs `querySelectorAll`, since I've seen some relatively poor performance from `qsa`. Sure enough, in the couple of browsers I ran it against, [qsa is slower](http://jsperf.com/id-starts-with-via-qsa-vs-tag-name-plus-filter). Firefox 5 is coming up with some crazy fast results for `...TagName`. Feels like something's wrong there.

Comment: @patrick It could be that the qSA implementation in the browsers uses the getElementsByTagName algorithm in cases where a type selector is present. The gEBTN method is certainly "more raw" then qSA, so I guess it's understandable that it's faster. However, the results in Opera are insane - 2.7 million ops/sec for qSA?! `:)`

Comment: Wow, that is pretty crazy with Opera. I wonder if it caches selections if there are no DOM changes, so only the first one is actually run (or something). I figure `qsa` will catch up eventually. Anyway, good answer, even if it was devoid of jQuery. ;o)

Comment: @patrick I've noticed that Opera returns results for `console.time`/`console.timeEnd` in microseconds, so I did some tests (I hope the results are reliable). I've executed [this function](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/F7y6H/1/) from within Opera's console while the homepage of StackOverflow was loaded. The results: qSA = cca. 350 μsec, gEBTN+filter = cca. 1700 μsec. Yup, qSA's considerably faster in Opera.

Comment: Well, that's good to know. Gives the others a standard to reach. I should pay more attention to Opera.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery you can do this simply like:

```
$('select[id^=TypeA]').bind('yourevent', function() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the event listener inline and directly pass the element.

```
<select onclick="myfunction(this)" id="<%= name %>" >
blah
blah 
</select>
```

Another thing you can do is pass the event attribute like this:

```
<select onclick="myfunction(event)" id="<%= name %>" >
blah
blah 
</select>
```

Then in myfunction, event.target will be the element that triggered the call.  You could get the id with `event.target.id`.

Comment: +1 Since I don't believe in the *unobtrusive JavaScript* religion. You can emulate the behavior of a regular handler by doing `myfunction.call( this, event )`, which will set `this` to the element, and send `event` as the argument (even in IE).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't know the ID specifically there are other things you can do.

One choice is to use a class name; another option is to prepend the ID with something static and (in jquery parlance) your can use a starts-with selector.

```
<select id="generated<%=name%>">

var mySelect = $('select[id^=generated]');
```

It will work but its not the best way of doing things, especially if you'll have more than one generated element. It's also relatively slow.

Selecting by CSS Class name would probably be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

if you have jQuery its easy with jQuery query selector. but if not:

1. Add a class to your element:

   ```
   <% class="myClass" name="TypeA" + specialIDString %>
   <select  id="<%= name %>" >
       blah
       blah 
   </select>
   ```
2. Use `getElementsByClassName` to reach your elements

   ```
   var myElems = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
   ```
3. Loop around elements and add event listener

   ```
   for(var i=0; i<myElems.length;  i++){
       myElems[i].addEventListener('click', function(){}, false);
   }
   ```

I know getElementsByClass name don't work in IE6 (or 7 also?). But this is my solution. Maybe I can update it with x-browser solution

Comment: Well, you just supply older versions of IE with an explicit definition of the `getElementsByClassName` function, so that's not an issue.